# Android chrome browser custom check input not working

Tags: android, jquery, html, mobile, checkbox

I have a list with titles. Each line has a custom check box. If I click on the check box it should change the `<img>` tag source attribute. On PC browser it's working good, but on my phone the image doesn't changed.

```
<div class='my-list' onClick='myFunction(this);'>
    <img src='' alt='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='selected' value='0' />
</div>

function myFunction(obj){

    if( $(obj).find('input').val() == '0' ){
        $(obj).find('input').val('1');
        $(obj).find('img').attr('src', 'images/check.gif');
    }
    else{
        $(obj).find('input').val('0');
        $(obj).find('img').attr('src', '');
    }

}
```

The first click it's working, but if I want to un-check, the image still remains in div. As I said it's working on my PC browser, but on my mobile device the image tag source doesn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class='my-list'>check box</div>
<img src='http://a.fsdn.com/allura/p/handbrake/icon' id='image' style='display: none;' />


$('.my-list').click(function() {    
  var image = '#image';   
  if($(image).css('display') == 'none') {  
    $(image).show();
  } else {
    $(image).hide();
  }    
});
```

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/MsGtL/